# Any better alternative for getting last record without limit

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a following query

```
DECLARE lv_Duration INT;    
    SET @lv_Duration = 0;    

     SELECT @lv_Duration := TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  changedon,NOW()) 
     FROM  `transactionhistory` 
     WHERE transaction_Id = TRIM(_transaction)        
     ORDER BY tsh_id DESC
     LIMIT 1;
```

In which I am getting time since last entry of transaction_Id fields.But it is taking .25 of a second in relative mid size table.My primary auto-increment field is tsh_id. I have index on  transaction_Id field. I think ordering and taking last record might have performance impact. so any alternative for it?

Comment: alternative way(i don't know if it's faster): add an index to the column 'tsh_id', omit the order by and limit clauses, add a filter to the where clause' and tsh_id = (select max(th2.tsh_id) from \`transactionhistory\` th2)'

Comment: I think after results i found your approach taking more time. May be my current way is most optimized

Comment: @KamranShahid After skimming through [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) page, I don't see any reason to believe yours is not optimized. I also ran an `EXPLAIN` on your query, and the one I previously posted as answer, and yours looks nicer. I am curious why you use a variable though, why not just select the timestampdiff result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`ORDER BY` optimisation link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) supplied by McAdam331 I believe your query matches the pattern:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM t1
   WHERE key_part1 = constant
ORDER BY key_part2;
```

A composite index on `(transaction_Id,tsh_id)` should speed this up.

I don't think there is a quicker way than `LIMIT` to get the latest record.